# After click approve button, automatically delete the old data

Tags: laravel

I have created a meeting room booking system using Laravel. So, I have 2 table, which is book for Auth::guest to book a room, and event for Auth::user to approve the booked room.

I have a view to list all the booking that have been made by the guest (/books) if auth::user is true, in the view, there is approve button which will take you to another view which is (events/create) which has a same form as the (/books/create) view.

When you click approve button, all the data of the booked will come out to the form in (events/create) because I have the $id of the booked data, so that I can do Book::findOrfail($id), and when hit the apply submit button, the data will be saved to the event table.

So, my question is how to automatically delete the booked data from book table after I hit the submit button on (events/create) view?

Any ideas?

Create events on event controller

```
 public function create_by_booking($id)
{
    $event = Book::findOrFail($id);
    $event->start_time =  $this->change_date_format_fullcalendar($event->start_time);
    $event->end_time =  $this->change_date_format_fullcalendar($event->end_time);

    $data = [
        'page_title' => 'Add new event',
        'event'         => $event,
        'count'  => Book::count(),
    ];

    return view('event/create', $data);
}
```

Create book from book controller

```
 public function create()
{
    $data = [
        'page_title' => 'Book Meeting Room',
        'count'  => Book::count(),
    ];

    return view('book/create', $data);
}
```

View for listing /books

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Booking's Title</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Room</th>
                    <th>Start</th>
                    <th>End</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php $i = 1;?>
                @foreach($books as $book)
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{ $i++ }}</th>
                        <td><a href="{{ url('books/' . $book->id) }}">{{ $book->title }}</a> <small>by {{ $book->name }}</small></td>
                        <td>{{ $book->email }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $book->room }}</td>
                        <td>{{ date("g:ia\, jS M Y", strtotime($book->start_time)) }}</td>
                        <td>{{date("g:ia\, jS M Y", strtotime($book->end_time)) }}</td>
                        @if (Auth::guest())

                        @else
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{{ url('/events/create', $book->id) }}">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add</a>
                            <form action="{{ url('books/' . $book->id) }}" style="display:inline" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                            </form>

                        </td>
                        @endif
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Thank you.

Comment: so far, how did you handle the events/create views? - i mean, the controllers..

Comment: Share your code

Comment: updated with code.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events

Comment: Just pass an ID of record to create event and then delete it with this ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already passing the `$event` variable for your view, which has the object of the book you searched for, so I think your `$event` now has an `id` property on it that you can access.

In your event/create view you can edit your route to the store method to accept the id so something like this:

```
<form action="{{ url('/events/store', $data['event']->id) }}" method="POST">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Since you didn't post your `store()` method I assume it's gonna look like this:

```
public function store($id) {  //of course edit your route to accept this variable

// here is where you process your events as you want.

$book = Book::find($id); //here is where you just find the book and delete it as you wanted.
$book->delete();

return redirect()->back();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not asking the technical in Laravel on how to delete a row..

So, you should call that function (ex. delete_booking($id)) once the function (event/create) is successful.

But my suggestion is, you don't need to delete booking data, but rather set a flag on that row to indicate that the booking is already taken to the next step.

If you are considering to save database size, the delete can be done in a batch like once a week, to clean up the booking table. IMHO, it's more efficient rather than doing it one by one automatically.

Comment: I want to do Book::find($id)->delete(); after the store function is success. How to pass $id to store function so that i can do Book::find($id)->delete(); ?